# selenium-how to click on link which is nested inside div

Tags: selenium

I have div and hyperlink like this:

```
<div id="food-add-actions" class="actions food_dialog fd_food_dialog_s-fndds2-f41210000">
  <div class="right">
     <a href="Javascript://" class="food-add-button add button"><span></span><span>Add to Food Log</span></a>
    <a href="Javascript://" class="edit button"><span></span><span>Edit</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

how can i click on this `Edit` hyperlink?

i tried below but it did not worked for me

```
driver.findElement(By.className("edit button")).click();
```

Comment: I think this question answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089492/selenium-webdriver-w-java-locating-elements-with-multiple-class-names-with-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you actually have is that you have a space in your By.className.

There is a question with a similar problem here.

[webdriver classname with space using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475449/webdriver-classname-with-space-using-java)

You should be able to select it with a By.css selector, such as.

```
By.css('.right a.button')
```