# InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to get each of the below elements using

```
element = driver.findElement(By.className("code-list-item code-list-item-public "));
```

The output of inspect element is as follows.

```
<div class="column one-fourth codesearch-aside"></div>

<div class="column three-fourths codesearch-results">

    <div class="sort-bar"></div>
    <div id="code_search_results">
        <div class="code-list">
            <div class="code-list-item code-list-item-public "></div>
            <div class="code-list-item code-list-item-public "></div>
            <div class="code-list-item code-list-item-public "></div>
            <div class="code-list-item code-list-item-public "></div>
            <div class="code-list-item code-list-item-public "></div>
            <div class="code-list-item code-list-item-public "></div>
            <div class="code-list-item code-list-item-public "></div>
            <div class="code-list-item code-list-item-public "></div>
            <div class="code-list-item code-list-item-public "></div>
            <div class="code-list-item code-list-item-public "></div>
        </div>
```

But it fails and throws the below error.

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector code-list-item code-list-item-public  is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
```

Also, How do I traverse through each of the classes? Each of these contain subparts which I would like to process further individually before moving to the next.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089492/selenium-webdriver-w-java-locating-elements-with-multiple-class-names-with-one)

Comment: So, when I try this , element = driver.findElement(By.className("code-list-item")); it works but when I try to use "code-list-item code-list-item-public " it does not.

Comment: Probably because `By.className(...)` doesn't accept multiple class names, if you want that, use the method that I've previously suggested or try to separate the class names with a `,`

Comment: @Zack the error tells you exactly what's happening. It is a compound class you you use `code-list-item code-list-item-public` combination of two different classes and when you use `code-list-item` it's only one class since it's also unique it works

Comment: @Saifur Yes . You are right. I got this. So each of the classes "code-list-item code-list-item-public " is inside the class "code-list". I need to traverse through all the "code-list-item code-list-item-public " classes . How do I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch all the `div` with compound class class `code-list-item code-list-item-public`? Which is 10 in count?

Comment: yes. If you see the image which I just attached, for each of the compound class "code-list-item code-list-item-public" I want to go to href link and click on it and then go to view code changes

Comment: @Zack I am getting confused with the `html` and the image you provided. Doesn't look same

Comment: @Saifur If you expand each of the code-list-item code-list-item-public div classes, you get something that is visible in the image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70928/discussion-between-saifur-and-zack).

Comment: Are you sure you really care only about the items with both classes? Just pick one and be happy. Otherwise you would have to get both and intersect the results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compound class names are not supported error in WebDriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699900/compound-class-names-are-not-supported-error-in-webdriver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about the class name that much if I don't have to. I would use css selector.

`.code-list>div`

Notice in css `.` means class so I am pointing to the div with the class `code-list` and `>div` it allows us to select all child div

You also can use `:nth-child()` function to grab a specific child div with index number

`.code-list>div:nth-child(1)`

The above css allows you to select the first child div

As per your screenshot

`.code-list>div:nth-child(1)>a`

A code block that may help OP to understand how this scenario should be handled

```
//maximizing the window for better view
driver.manage().window().maximize();

//a selector to find all the links on the page
By selector = By.xpath("//p[@class='title']/a[1]");

//finding the list of all elements
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(selector);

/*Iterating over the collection may throw StaleElementReference exception due to DOM refresh
according to my knowledge for loop is best in such case
*/
for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){

    new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(selector));

    //Click on the title
    driver.findElements(selector).get(i).click();

    //Navigating back to the main page. This is not feasible but no other option present due to page structure
    driver.navigate().back();
}
```